# Ubuntu 22.04 safely exit emergency mode

Tags: boot, grub2, system, system-settings, user-management

Uhm, I run into trouble attempting a rollback of packages installed today.
I executed this:

```
grep "2022-10-20.*.install " /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d: -f1 | xargs sudo apt-get --yes purge
```

Now I turned on the system just to be "welcomed" with  screen showing strange message and blicking (expecting user input) .

```
...
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (202110730/psargs-330)
[  0.368876] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU5._CPC due to previous error
# and messages similar  to this

/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 646545/32022528 files, 34255084/12806988 blocks
[UNSUPP] Starting of Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point unsupported.
[ 3.961792] FAT-fs (sda1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to  view system logs,
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

When I typed `exit`, I get:

```
root@Pedro:~#
```

I am not sure how to safely reboot my system.

How can you help?

Comment: Roll back is not something that Ubuntu supports.

Comment: To reboot the system, enter the command `reboot`. Try running the command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall the GUI